# Joining two arrays using jQuery "extend" returns one array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a simple joining of two one-dimensional arrays and the result is content of one array or the other, depending on how I use "$.extend". Obviously I am doing something wrong but can't see it.

Simplified example is:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
var joined1 = [];
var joined2 = [];
....
....
// "1" and "2" below are result of evaluation of some session variables
// I also need to keep contents of array1 and array2
array1 = "1".split(','); // length 1, ["1"]
array2 = "2".split(','); // length 1, ["2"]

var joined1 = $.extend({}, array1, array2); // joined1 has one element ["2"]

// clone array2
var joined2 = array2.slice(0); // ["2"]
$.extend(joined2, array1);     // joined2 = ["1"]
```

I guess I can use javascript and "foreach" to accomplish this but need to know what I am doing wrong with "extend" for possible future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because `$.extend` is intended for use with objects, not arrays.

As you're using it with an array it's taking the index of each element in that array as the key. As such the second array *overwrites* the first when using `$.extend` as, once interpreted as an object, both have values at key `0`.

If you're trying to join two arrays you don't need jQuery. Use the native [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method:

```js
let array1 = "1,11".split(',');
let array2 = "2,22".split(','); 
let joined = array1.concat(array2);

console.log(joined);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was meant for array of objects. I ended up using a variant of your suggestion: joined= $.unique([].concat.apply([], [array1, array2)).sort(); I had to also ensure no duplicates existed and preserve initial arrays.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just FYI you can simplify that call: `let joined = $.unique(array1.concat(array2)).sort();`